# Defining multiple projections inside a file gdb [error 000289 failed to alter spatial reference]?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, coordinate-system, file-geodatabase

I am importing multiple shapefiles into a filegdb in ArcGIS 10, and using the following code to define the projection of the feature once imported, to the .prj of the original .shp file.

Here is my code:

```
for spatial in SpatialRefList:
    del gp
    import arcpy as gp
    print 'DEFINING PROJECTION'

    print 'FEATURECLASS = ' + str(featureclass)
    print 'PROJECTION = ' + str(prjfile)
    time.sleep(1)
    try:


        gp.DefineProjection_management(featureclass, prjfile)

    except:
        traceback.print_exc()
        time.sleep(2)
```

However the code is throwing up error 000289 - failed to alter spatial reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GDBs are just like a file tree structure. Feature Datasets can only contain feature classes in one spatial reference.
However there is another object called a feature dataset that will allow you to seperate and assign different references per feature dataset.
[esri help feature dataset](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002300000001000000.htm)
[esri hellp creating feature dataset (code)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//0017000000pv000000)

Comment: thanks for the link, you cleared up my confusion as to why each featureclass didn't just act in the same way as a shapefile. I am in fact using feature datasets (one per country) in my file gdb structure - however I was trying to change each featureclass's sp ref individually. Cheers Again I'll amend my code to set each featuredatasets prj!

Comment: @brad-nesom, feature classes within a gdb that are not within a feature dataset can have any spatial reference. Alex was using feature datasets, thus the error message.